How to reroute traffic on a local Ubuntu Machine without Traffic Getting Caught in a Loop
I need help rerouting traffic on my ubuntu virtual machine running on parallels for port 443 with a tunnel url to port 1111 on the same ubuntu machine. Once that is successfull the server at 1111 should then forward the request to the tunnel url. For some reason when I try using iptables and HAProxy it doesn't work
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

For IPTables
I've tried setting the ip_forward config flag to 1 if thats what you call it.
I've tried setting the prerouting config to the following:
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d rnqhc-adas-ads-ed01-cb00-sada-asdds-asdd-iii.a.free.pinggy.link --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:1111

Then I've masqueraded it.

And added
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -d rnqhc-adas-ads-ed01-cb00-sada-asdds-asdd-iii.a.free.pinggy.link -j ACCEPT

I've also seen answers by:
IPTables reroute traffic not working
but it did not help.
For HAProxy I've tried:
frontend https_front
    bind *:443 ssl crt /home/devhouse/Developer/mycert_combined.pem
    acl host_mydomain hdr(host) rnqhc-adas-ads-ed01-cb00-sada-asdds-asdd-iii.a.free.pinggy.link
    use_backend my_backend if host_mydomain

backend my_backend
    server local_proxy 127.0.0.1:1111

I think I'm missing something

There are a couple of moments in your rules.

If you're using the 127.0.0. address in a DNAT rule, it also requires enabling of the net.ipv4.conf.<iface_name>.route_localnet=1 sysctl variable. Write it in a sysctl.conf file and run the sysctl -p --system to apply the changes.

To reroute the locally originated traffic (from HA Proxy in your case) you should add the same DNAT rule into the nat/OUTPUT chain.

Avoid usage of domain names in your rules. It can cause various issues if dns doesn't work.


How to troubleshoot:

Check the rules counters with iptables-save -c.

Check the conntrack events with conntrack -E.

Use the tcpdump to sniff the traffic.


